# Session Management with Java Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Hibernate-based platform, built from stateless servlets (one is used to register a user and the rest to query the db).

I'm using Hibernate's sessions as follows:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
if ((null == session) || (session.isOpen() == false)) {
  session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

Currently I do not close the session at the end of the servlet in order to avoid `openSession()` call (trying to use opened sessions if possible).

What's the best practice ? when am I supposed to close these sessions ?

Can you please give an example ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 16):

The best practice is in most cases session-per-request. That is, open a session in the beginning of handling a request, and close it in the end. You can do that in a Servlet `Filter`, for example.

Having one session for the entire application is bad, because it will accumulate a lot of entities in its 1st level cache, which is a memory leak. It may also produce undeterministic results when multiple clients use it at the same time.

Your code, however, is not using one session for the entire application - it is using the "current session" concept, which opens a session and stores it in a context (a `ThreadLocal` for example). But if you don't close it, it will stay there forever. Plus, it will cause the same problems as described above, because threads are reused in a web application, and a new request will get an old, unclosed session at some point.

Comment: I agree that one session for the entire application is a bad idea, but how about getting current session for each request instead of open close session, especially when you are applying spring and hibernate together?

Answer (score 5):

Its always better to open a new session for every request, and close the session once the request is processed. Like

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

instead of

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

If we use the getCurrentSession() method , tansaction.commit() / rollback() closes the connection.

Comment: "new session for every request" is anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

The best is to manage a hibernate session is to open a new session for every request.
It all depends on how you obtain the session.

- if you use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(), you'll obtain a
  "current session" which is bound to the lifecycle of the transaction
  and will be automatically flushed and closed when the transaction
  ends (commit or rollback)
- if you decide to use sessionFactory.openSession(), you'll have to
  manage the session yourself and to flush and close it "manually".

> ```
> if (!session.isOpen()) {
>         session = session.getSessionFactory().openSession();
>         session.beginTransaction();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I better recommend you to use spring framework. Cause in spring you can use `@Transactional` at method level and session will be automatically created and closed by transaction manager (unless you are using any open session in view interceptor) using `AOP` which is internally handled by framework.

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;

@Transactinal
void save(User user){
   em.persist(user);
}
```

thats all.spring is fun :D