# hibernate error when I try to delete

Tags: hibernate

I have a datatable that contains all my objects, list of manufacturer "Fabricant" and two buttons: update and delete.

```
public class FabricantService {

private FabricantHome dao ;
Session sesion ;
List<Fabricant> list;

    public FabricantService() {
        super();
        dao = new FabricantHome();
    }



    public void ajouter(Fabricant cart) {

        sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        sesion.beginTransaction();
        dao.persist(cart);
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
              } 



    public void update(Fabricant cart) {
            sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            sesion.beginTransaction();
            dao.merge(cart);
            sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    } 


   public void deletee (Fabricant cart) {
         sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
         sesion.beginTransaction();
         dao.delete(cart);
         sesion.getTransaction().commit();                      
}

public List<Fabricant> list(){
    sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    list=dao.findAll() ;
    return list;

    }


}
```

update OK it is fine it redirect me on a page to update one manufacturer.

but when I chose to delete this one this error is shown:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: 
   org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
      Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions  
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)     
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: This thread might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367886/session-management-with-java-hibernate

Comment: thx a lot for your helpe ..It helpe me understand something  new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After commit close the session.

Comment: thx ,I make after the methode deletee sesion.close();  but there is an error Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.ardiagia.persistance.Fabricant#1]

Comment: Try session.flush() after closing session. Flush will persist your data and clear session.

Comment: thank you, the selected line was removed, but there was a new error here ::::::: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Comment: I forgot to do that at my body methods
session.getTansaction (). beginTransaction ()
then here one of the operation
and the last is commit ();  Thx a lot my friend

Comment: Your welcome anytime bro. FYI instead of thanx you can up vote or accept answer if it helps you in any way, there is a method of SO, I am not telling you to do that but take in consideration my friend.