# How to use hibernate-sessions properly?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

From what I have read you create a session per request and close the session after the request has finished.

Would this be right usage of sessions in hibernate?

1. start server and create SessionFactory
2. user want to query data from database
   2.1 `Session userSession = MyHibernateClass.getFactory().openSession();`
3. do one query
4. `session.close();`

When do I use `getCurrentSession()` and when `openSession()` ?

Comment: Take a look at the answers of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367886/session-management-with-java-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SessionFactory.openSession()
```

always opens a new session that you have to close once you are done with the operations.
    SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
returns a session bound to a context - you don't need to close this.
For more detailed information you can follow given link
[openSession() v/s getCurrentSession()](https://java2blog.com/difference-opensession-getcurrentsession-hibernate/)